# How to cut rasters with a shapefile object in loop by folder in R?

Tags: r, loops, raster, shapefile, cut

How guys. How are you?

I am happy to greet you.

I'm trying to cut rasters (tif) from shapefile objects

The structure of my data is as follows:

(Seed Folder)

Specie 1 <- model1.tif, model2.tif, model3.tif, cut1.shp

Specie 2 <- model1.tif, model2.tif, model3.tif, cut1.shp

Specie 3 <- model1.tif, model2.tif, model3.tif, cut1.shp

I have different folders from different species. In every folders I have differents tiff models and differents shapefiles. What I need is a script that cuts all the raster inside of that species folder using the shapefile file in the same folder. And then go the next folder to do the same. I don't need to cut files that are not in the same folder. I'm trying with the next code with no success. I am a relatively new user in R, so I would  appreciate any help. Thank you guys. Have a nice day.

```
setwd ("H:/Tesis_maestria/1_Eliposides/1_Cut_models")
library(purrr)
library(kuenm)
library(raster)
library(maptools)
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)
rm(list=ls())

path_general <- "H:/Tesis_maestria/1_Eliposides/1_Cut_models"


dirs_especies_path <- list.dirs(full.names = T,
                                recursive = F)

datum <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84")

x=1
y=1
resultados_all <- seq_along(dirs_especies_path) %>% purrr::map_df(function(x){
   sp_mods <- list.files(dirs_especies_path[x], pattern = ".tif", full.names = TRUE)
   M <-list.files(dirs_especies_path[x], pattern=".shp", full.names = TRUE)
   r1 <- raster(sp_mods[y])
   cut_all <- seq_along(sp_mods) %>%  purrr::map_df(function(y){
   cor <-crop(r1,M)
   mas<-mask(cor,M)
   return(cut_all)
    })
     nwdf <- data.frame(cut_all,
                     sp_name=dirs_especies_names[x])
                         setwd("H:/Tesis_maestria/1_Eliposides/1_Cut_models/cut")
    writeRaster(cut_all,filename=paste(M[[i]]),bylayer=T,suffix=names(stac),format="GTiff")
  return(nwdf)
})
print(resultados_all)
```

Answer (score 0):

After a day work i could run this code successfully. As it follows. I hope this could help someone with the same issue. Regards.

```
rm(list=ls())
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(maptools)
library(rgeos)
library(purrr)
rm(list=ls())

setwd("H:/Tesis_maestria/1_Eliposides/1_Cut_models1")
datum <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84")

path_general <- "H:/Tesis_maestria/1_Eliposides/1_Cut_models1"

dirs_especies_path <- list.dirs(full.names = T,
                                recursive = F)
                                
dirs_especies_names <- list.dirs(full.names = F,
                                 recursive = F)
                                 
#paste(path_general,dirs_especies_names,sep="")

##Presente##
for (i in 1:length(dirs_especies_path)){
    M <- list.files(dirs_especies_path[i],pattern = "csv.shp$",full.names = TRUE)
    mods <- list.files(dirs_especies_path[i],pattern = ".tif$",full.names = TRUE)
    stack <- raster::stack(mods)
    Ms <- shapefile(M)
    Ms@proj4string <- datum
    cor <- crop(stack,Ms)
    mas <- mask(cor,Ms)
    writeRaster(mas,filename=paste(M),bylayer=T,suffix=names(stack),format="GTiff")
    next}
```